# Proof of $\left(K_{1} \cap K_{2}\right)^{*}=K_{1}^{*}+K_{2}^{*}:$ the dual of intersection of convex cones is the sum of their duals

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be pointed closed convex cone in $E$ such that $K_{1 }∩ K_2 \neq \emptyset$.
>
> Show that
>   $\left(K_{1} \cap K_{2}\right)^{*}=K_{1}^{*}+K_{2}^{*}$
>
> under an appropriate assumption on $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$.

I have managed to show $K_{1}^{*}+K_{2}^{*}  \subseteq \left(K_{1} \cap K_{2}\right)^{*} $ without making any assumptions, but I have a hard time showing $\left(K_{1} \cap K_{2}\right)^{*}\subseteq K_{1}^{*}+K_{2}^{*}$.

would appreciate some help

Comment: Assume the claim does not hold. Then try to use a separation argument. Many results in convex analysis are like this: one direction is easy (and useless), the other is hard (because one has to use a separation argument).

Comment: This question is quite imprecise. You could use, e.g. the assumption $K_1 = K_2 = \{0\}$.

Comment: The title is inconsistent in describing $(K_{1} \cap K_{2})^{*}$ as the dual of the union of $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$.  You've written the dual of the intersection of the cones.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers, i updated it now.

Comment: There is  counter example if you only assume the closedness, I am not sure about the pointedness. Therefore if you want to prove it, you must somehow use the fact the cone are pointed.

Answer (score 2):

The proof only needs a basic property of dual cone:
$$
\begin{align}
K_1 \subseteq K_2 \implies K_1^* \supseteq K_2^*, \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
which is easy to verify.

Apply (1) to $K_1 \cap K_2$, and $K_1,K_2$, we have
\begin{align}
    \left.\begin{array}{l}
    (K_1 \cap K_2) \subseteq K_1 \implies
    (K_1 \cap K_2)^* \supseteq K_1^* \\
    (K_1 \cap K_2) \subseteq K_2 \implies
    (K_1 \cap K_2)^* \supseteq K_2^* \\
    \end{array}\right\} \implies
    (K_1 \cap K_2)^* \supseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Take convex hull of both side of (2). Left side won't change, and right side becomes $K_1^*+K_2^*$:
\begin{equation}
    (K_1 \cap K_2)^* \supseteq K_1^* + K_2^*. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Apply (1) to $K_1^* \cup K_2^*$, and $K_1^*,K_2^*$ similarly, we have
\begin{align}
    \left.\begin{array}{l}
    K_1^* \subseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*) \implies
    K_1^{**} \supseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*)^* \\
    K_2^* \subseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*) \implies
    K_2^{**} \supseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*)^*
    \end{array}\right\} \implies
    (K_1^{**} \cap K_2^{**}) \supseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*)^*. \tag{4}
\end{align}
Apply (1) to (4):
\begin{align}
             (K_1^{**} \cap K_2^{**})^* & \subseteq (K_1^* \cup K_2^*)^{**} \\
\end{align}
For any set $K$, dual cone of dual cone is the convex hull of origin set, i.e., $K^{**}=\operatorname{ConvexHull}(K)$, so
\begin{align}
    \implies (K_1 \cap K_2)^* & \subseteq \operatorname{ConvexHull}(K_1^* \cup K_2^*) \\
    \implies (K_1 \cap K_2)^* & \subseteq K_1^* + K_2^* \tag{5}
\end{align}

(3)(5) implies $$(K_1 \cap K_2)^* = K_1^* + K_2^*$$

Actually, this holds not only for closed convex cone $K_1, K_2$, but also holds for arbitrary set $K_1,K_2$.

Comment: Your proof is flawed.
$K_1^* \cup K_2^*$ is not necessarily convex, therefore if you take the dual of the dual, it is not $K_1^* \cup K_2^*$ anymore, even you assume both $K_1$ and $K_2$ are closed. In fact there is counter example, if only the closedness are assumed, I am not sure about pointed.

Comment: @pew Yes, you are right. The second line of (5) should be deleted. $(K_1^*\cup K_2^*)^{**}$ is not equal to $K_1^*\cup K_2^*$ but the convex hull of $K_1^*\cup K_2^*$, which is $K_1^*+K_2^*$.

Comment: @pew I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I think the conclusion is not correct, the two are not usually equal, in fact the first one is equal to the closure of the second one, no the proof can not be correct