# How to prove this (corollary of) hyperplane separation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

$X$ is a nonempty convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose element is $x=\left(x_1,...,x_n\right)$.

The theorem is as follows.

If for each $x\in X$, there is an $i \in \left\{1,...,n\right\}$ such that $x_i>0$,
then there exists $\left(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\right)$ where $\lambda_i \geqslant 0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$, such that
$\lambda \cdot x \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in X$
and $\lambda \cdot x>0$, for some $x \in X$.

I was wondering how to prove it. It looks like it is a corollary of the hyperplane separation theorem. "$\geqslant 0$ for all $x$ and $>0$ for some $x$" is a little bit weird and I do not know whether there is a version of the hyperplane separation theorem that has this form and can be applied to prove it.

[image]

Comment: The tricky part here is the $\lambda^T x>0$ part.

Comment: @copper.hat I think one can use hyperplane separation theorem to get $\lambda^T x \geqslant 0$ for all $x$. But how can I prove $\lambda^T x>0$ for some $x?$

Comment: By induction on the dimension. The existence of a $\lambda$ for which $\lambda.x \geq 0$ is just an application of the separation theorem between $C$ and the convex set $\bigcap x_i<0$. Now if for every $x$, $\lambda.x =0$, $C$ is contained in some hyperplane...

Comment: @Thomas I considered the case of $n=2$, as shown in the graph (the solid line indicates the hyperplane $\lambda$). Note that $X$ (the red segment) must be on one side of the origin, so there should be another hyperplane $\lambda'$ (dashed line) such that $\lambda' \cdot x>0$ for some $x$. But I don't know how to formalize it. Or maybe I misunderstood your method?

Comment: try to argue by induction on the dimension of the space : there is no difficulty unless all the figure is contained in some hyperplane..

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I still don't get it. It is indeed possible that for every $x$, $\lambda \cdot x=0$. What does "induction on the dimension" mean? Consider $\cap_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \leqslant 0$ rather than$\cap_{i=1}^{n} x_i \leqslant 0$?

Comment: Let $N = \{x | x_k \le 0 \text{ for all } k \}$. Note that $X$ does not intersect $N$. This gives a non zero $\lambda \ge 0$ that separates. But more work is needed to show some $x$ such that $\lambda^T x >0$.

Comment: @copper.hat The reason I asked this question is exactly about this "more work"...

Comment: That is why I deleted my answer, I'm still working on the more work part :-).

Comment: This is tougher than I thought.

Comment: This is driving me insane.

Comment: Cross-posted a week later at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428163/how-to-prove-this-corollary-of-hyperplane-separation-theorem.

Comment: One of the answers on MO is simple but very subtle.

Comment: @Ypbor I added an elaboration of Fedor's answer from MO here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary, constructive-ish proof similar to the one given by [Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428165/107094) using the Hyperplane Separation Theorem (HST):

By assumption both $X$ and $Y=ℝ_{≤0}^n$ are non-empty disjoint convex subsets of $V=ℝ^n$. Hence, by the HST, there exists a non-zero vector $v∈ℝ^n$ and scalar $c∈ℝ$ such that

$$∀x∈X:⟨x∣v⟩≥c  \quad\text{and}\quad ∀y∈Y : ⟨y∣v⟩≤c$$

We call such a tuple $(v, c)$ *feasible* (for both $X$ and $Y$).

###### Lemma 1: $(v, c)$ is feasible for $Y$ if and only if $c≥0$ and $v∈ℝ_{≥0}^n$, i.e. $v_i≥0$ for all $i$

**Proof:**  $c≥0$ since $0∈Y⟹0=⟨0∣v⟩≤c$. Choosing $y=-αe_i∈ℝ_{≤0}^{n}$, we have $-αv_i =⟨v∣-αe_i⟩≤c$ for all $α>0$, hence $v_i≥0$. On the other hand, if $v∈ℝ_{≥0}^n$ and $c≥0$, then since $Y=ℝ_{≤0}^n$ we have $⟨v∣y⟩≤0≤c$ for all $y∈Y$. ∎

###### Corollary 1: If $(v, c)$ is feasible, then $(v, 0)$ is feasible

**Proof:** Since Lemma 1 ensures $c≥0$, we have $⟨v∣x⟩≥c≥0$ for all $x∈X$, so $(v, 0)$ is also feasible for $X$. ∎

##### From here, we can prove the theorem through recursion

**Case 1:** There exists some $x∈X$ with $⟨v∣x⟩>0$. Note that if $\dim(V)=1$, then this is guaranteed, since by assumption we'd have $X⊆(0, ∞)$.

**Case 2:** $⟨v∣x⟩=0$ for all $x∈X$, i.e. $X⊂\operatorname{span}(\{v\})^⟂≕V'$. In this case, reduce the problem to the separation problem in $n-1$ dimensions: $X'≔X∩V'$ and $Y'≔Y ∩ V'$ are both non-empty convex subsets in the linear subspace $V'⊂V$. Note that $X'=X$, since $X⊂V'$.

Thus, by the HST there is a feasible tuple $(v', c')$ for this subproblem. Note that this is not necessarily feasible for the original problem, since we are not guaranteed $⟨v'∣y⟩≤c'$ for all $y∈Y$. However, we can construct a new proposal solution for the original problem through a convex combination:

$$ \tilde{v} = (1-α)v + αv' \qquad \text{and} \qquad \tilde{c} = (1-α)c + αc'$$

We need to prove that this is feasible for the original problem for some $α∈(0,1]$.

###### Lemma 2: $(v', c')$ is feasible for $Y'$ if and only if $c'≥0$ and if $v_i'≥0$ whenever $v_i=0$

**Proof:** $c'≥0$ again because $0∈Y'$. If $v_i=0$, then $e_i \perp v$, hence $\operatorname{cone}(-e_i)⊆Y'$, thus $⟨v'∣ -αe_i⟩ = -αv_i'≤c'$ for all $α>0$. Use the same limit argument as in Lemma 1. On the other hand, since $Y'=\operatorname{cone}(\{-e_i∣v_i=0\})$ we have

$$⟨v'∣y'⟩ = \sum_{i: v_i=0} \underbrace{v_i'}_{≥0} \underbrace{y_i'}_{≤0} + \sum_{i: v_i>0} v_i'\underbrace{y_i'}_{=0} ≤ 0 ≤ c' \qquad\text{for all $y'∈Y'$} \qquad ∎$$

###### Corollary 2: $(\tilde{v}, \tilde{c})$ is feasible for the original problem for some $α∈(0,1]$

Note that any convex combination is feasible for $X$. To get feasibility for $Y$, we need to ensure $\tilde{v}∈ℝ_{≥0}^n$. Using Lemma $2$, we have

$$∀i: (1-α)v_i + αv_i' \overset{!}{≥}0 ⟺ α(v_i-v_i') ≤ v_i \overset{(2)}{⟺} α ≤ \min_{i: v_i≠0} \frac{v_i}{|v_i-v_i'|}∈(0,1] \qquad ∎$$

Now, our new solution either satisfies case (1), or we repeat the argument using $V'=\operatorname{span}(\{v, v'\})^\perp$.

---

Finally, note that if $(v,0)$ is feasible, then so is the normalized $(λ, 0)$ with $λ = \frac{v}{∑_i v_i} ∈Δ^{n-1}$.

[image]

Comment: What are the various quantities in the statement of the last Corollary?

Comment: @copper.hat $(v, c)$ is the feasible solution to the original problem (separating $X$ and $Y$ in $V$), $(v', c')$ is the feasible solution to the subproblem (separating $X'$ and  $Y'$ in $V'$), and $(\tilde{v}，\tilde{c}) = \big((1-α)v+αv'，(1-α)c+αc'\big)$ is a convex combination of the two, which is shown to be also a solution to separating $X$ and $Y$ in $V$ for some $α>0$.

Comment: Minor detail, in Case 2 above, it may be that $X'$ is the empty set. For example, take $X=\{0\} \times (0, \infty)$ and $v=(1,0)$. This complicates the inductive approach.

Comment: @copper.hat No, that can't happen. We know $⟨v∣x⟩≥0$ for all $x∈X$, and so if $⟨v∣x⟩=0$ for all $x∈X$ it follows $X⊂\operatorname{span}(\{v\})^⟂≕V'$. In your example, $v=(1,0)$, so $V'=\operatorname{span}(\{(0,1)\})$ and $X'≔X∩V'=X$.

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't drink & derive.

Comment: How do you ensure $v$ and $v'$ are not linear correlated?

Comment: @Ypbor By construction $v'$ is orthogonal to $v$ (and in later iterations the new vector is constructed from the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}(\{v, v', v'', v''', …\})$

Comment: @Hyperplane The existence of $v'$ is based on HST, so what do you mean by "by construction"?

Comment: @Ypbor $v'$ was constructed by applying HST in the space $V'$, which is orthogonal to $v$. So since $v'∈V'$, it is orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: @Hyperplane Could you please clarify the meaning of superscription $\bot$? I thought it means the set of all vectors that are orthogonal with the vectors beneath it. If that is the case, is $span(\left\{v,v'\right\})^{\bot}$ the same as $\left\{v,v'\right\}^{\bot}$?

Comment: I feel that the "if" part of Lemma 2 is not used later. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: For the recursion, I feel that one should use $span(\left\{v, \tilde{v}\right\})$ rather than $span(\left\{v, v'\right\})$ because both $v$ and $\tilde{v}$ are orthogonal with $X$?

Comment: @Ypbor  $U^⟂ ≔ \{v∈V∣∀u∈U: ⟨v∣u⟩=0\}$ is the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement). Using this defnition you'd technically you'd have $\{v, v'\}^⟂ = \operatorname{span}(\{v,v'\})^⟂$, but usually it is only applied to subspaces. Regarding Lemma 2, the condition on the $v_i'$ is used to prove corollary 2. Finally, in the recursive case it doesn't make a difference because in this case $\operatorname{span}(\{v,v'\}) = \operatorname{span}(\{v,\tilde{v}\})$.

Comment: And I was thinking whether it is possible to borrow the idea from @copper.hat 's answer. That is, there exists $x$ such that $\langle v'|x\rangle>0$. Then it is impossible that $\langle \tilde{v} | x \rangle=0$ for all $x \in X$ and we don't even need the recursion.

Comment: My understanding is that the "only if" part rather than the "if" part of Lemma 2 is used to prove Corollary 2.

Comment: And what is the final contradiction in the process of recursion?

Comment: @Ypbor there is no contradiction process. It is a direct proof: either we have case 1 and are done, or we have case 2. In the latter case we construct a new feasible solution. Again, either this new solution satisfies case 1 or it doesn't, in which case we apply case 2 again. This process must stop after a maximum of $n-2$ iterations since the dimension of $V'$ starts with $n-1$ and decreases by $1$ with each iteration, and case 1 is guaranteed to happen in the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: There is an implicit recursion in my answer when the extension of $\eta$ is developed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tedious elaboration of Fedor Petrov's simple but subtle answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/428210/31729.

From Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis: Theorem 11.3. Let $C_1,C_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be non empty convex sets. In order that there exist a hyperplane separating separating $C_1$ and $C_2$ properly, it is necessary & sufficient that
$\operatorname{ri} C_1$ and $\operatorname{ri} C_2$ have no point in common.

Let $N = \{x | x_k \le 0 \text{ for all } k \}$. Let $Y = \operatorname{sp} X$ and $C = Y \cap N$. Since $X$ & $C$ are disjoint the above gives the existence of some non zero functional $\eta$ on $Y$ that separates $C,X$. We can assume that $\eta \le 0$ on $C$ (since $0 \in C$) and $\eta \ge 0$ on $X$.

Since $Y$ is the span of $X$, $Y$ has a basis composed of elements of $X$. Since $\eta \ge 0$ is non zero, it must be strictly greater then zero on at least one of the basis elements.
That is, $\eta(x) >0$ for some $ x \in X$.

All that remains is to show that we can express $\eta (x) = \sum_k \eta_k x_k$ for some $\eta_k \ge 0$. This is the subtle part of Fedor's answer.

Minor digression to review some facts about dual cones & linear functionals.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces, we can identify
any linear functional with an element of that space. For example, let $\xi_\eta \in Y$ be the element corresponding to the linear functional $\eta$ so that $\eta(y) = \langle \xi_\eta, y \rangle$. We want to show that $\xi_\eta \ge 0$.

The subtle point of the proof (to me, at least) is the following: Suppose $\lambda$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then clearly
$\lambda |_Y$ (the restriction of $\lambda$ to $Y$) is a linear
functional on $Y$ as well. Then $\xi_\lambda$ is not necessarily
equal to $\xi_{\lambda |_Y}$. However, for any $y \in Y$ we have
$\lambda(y) = \langle \xi_\lambda, y \rangle = \langle \xi_{\lambda |_Y}, y \rangle$.

For any set $K$ the dual cone is given by $K^* = \{ x | \langle k, x \rangle \ge 0 \text{ for all } k \in K \}$. Note that the dual is a subset of the relevant ambient Hilbert space.

If $A \subset B$ then $B^* \subset A^*$.

If $K_1,...,K_p$ are any sets, then
$(K_1 \cap \cdots \cap K_p)^* = K_1^* + \cdots + K_p^*$ (see [Proof of $\left(K_{1} \cap K_{2}\right)^{*}=K_{1}^{*}+K_{2}^{*}:$ the dual of intersection of convex cones is the sum of their duals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356026/27978)).

If $K$ is a closed convex cone then $K^{**} = K$.

If we let $\operatorname{cone} K$ denote the smallest convex cone containing $K$, then we see that for any set $K$ we have $K^{**} = \overline{\operatorname{cone}} K $, the smallest closed convex cone containing $K$.

Also note that for any element
$x$, we have $\{x\}^{**} = \operatorname{cone} \{x\}$, the ray passing through $x$.

Let $e_k(x) = x_k$ be the coordinate functionals. Then I claim that if $y \in Y$ is such that $e_k(y) \ge 0$ for all $k$, then $\eta(y) \ge 0$. Suppose not, then $\eta(y) <0$ and since $y \ge 0$ we see that $-y \le 0$ and so $-y \in C$ and $\eta(-y) >0$ which is a contradiction. Hence we have
$\{\xi_{e_1 |_Y} \}^* \cap \cdots \cap \{ \xi_{e_n |_Y} \}^* \subset \{ \xi_{\eta |_Y} \}^*$.

From above we have
$( \{\xi_{e_1 |_Y} \}^* \cap \cdots \cap \{ \xi_{e_n |_Y} \}^* )^* = \operatorname{cone} \{\xi_{e_1 |_Y}\} + \cdots + \operatorname{cone} \{ \xi_{e_n |_Y} \}$ and so
$\operatorname{cone} \{\xi_{\eta |_Y} \}  \subset \operatorname{cone} \{\xi_{e_1 |_Y}\} + \cdots + \operatorname{cone} \{\xi_{e_n |_Y}\}$. In particular,
we can write $\xi_{\eta |_Y} = \sum_k \eta_k \xi_{e_k |_Y}$ for
some $\eta_k \ge 0$.

Finally, extend $\eta$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by letting $\eta(x) = \sum_k \eta_k x_k = \langle \sum_k \eta_k \xi_{e_k}, x \rangle $ and note that
$\eta(y) \ge 0$ for all $y \in X$, $\eta(x) \le 0$ for all $x \in N$. Furthermore, there is some $x \in X$ such that $\eta(x) >0$.

To finish, let $\lambda = {1 \over \sum_k \eta_k} \xi_\eta$.

Comment: As for the subtle part, I feel that first we can write $\eta$ as $\langle v', x\rangle$ for some $v'\in Y$. And then find $\hat{v}$ in $R_{+}^n$ such that the projection of $\hat{v}$ on $Y$ is $v'$. This is shown in https://imgur.com/a/bU4ywxD. Is it possible to formalize this idea?

Comment: Yes, you can use any $v'$ of the form $\hat{v}+w$ where $w \bot Y$.

Comment: How can one prove that there exists $w$ such that $\hat{v}+w \in \mathbb{R}_+^n \backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, that is the point of the last two paragraphs above.

Comment: I mean to formalize the naive idea that "as long as $w$ is long enough, it will eventually penetrate the positive orthant". https://imgur.com/a/vdESRPx