# Questions related to Cones and Subspaces of Euclidean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-cone, dual-cone

> Cone: A subset $ S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a cone if $\alpha \geq 0 \implies \alpha S \subseteq S.$

> Polar: A Polar $K^*$ of a cone $K$ is a closed convex cone such that
> $$K^*=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x\in K \implies (x,y) \geq 0\}$$
> where $(x,y)$ denote the standard inner product of vectors.

**Problem** If $K=\mathbb{R}^n_+ \cap R(A^T)$ then $K^*=\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A)$ where $A \in R^{m \times n}$ and $R(A),N(A)$ denote the range and null space of $A.$

**Question** How to approach this problem ? I know polar of a set is orthogonal to the original set and $N(A)$ and $R(A^T)$ is orthogonal for any matrix. Now how to reach to the desire result ?

Thank in advanced.

**Edit:** The dual of the intersection of the convex cones is the sum of their dual.

Since $(\mathbb{R}^n_+)^*=\mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $(R(A^T))^*=N(A)$ then
$K^*=\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A)$
where $K=\mathbb{R}^n_+ \cap R(A^T)$.

Thanks copper.hat

Comment: This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356026/27978

Comment: By using the fact that for convex cones $K_1, K_2$ we have $(K_1 + K_2)^*= K_1^* \cap K_2^*$ we get $(\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A))^*= K$ so $K^{*} = (\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A))^{**}=\overline{\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A)}$. It remains to show that $\mathbb{R}^n_+ +N(A)$ is closed (which I'm not sure how to do).

Comment: You cannot use the linked answer directly as $R(A^T)$ is NOT a pointed cone (a cone is called pointed if $x\in C$ and $-x \in C$ implies $x=0$). This is most definitely not the case with $R(A^T)$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thank You for replaying also can we suggest some basics reference for articles for cones and matrices and connection between them.

Comment: @Mani You should be able to find all the relevant definitions in any convex analysis and/or convex optimization book. I don't know what you mean by "connection between cones and matrices".

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: @copper.hat Thankyou! I'm busy in some other work.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion :-).

Let $K^+ = \{ x | \langle y, x \rangle \ge 0 \text{ for all } y \in K \}$. The key results are that if $K$ is a closed convex cone then $K^{++} = K$ and if $A \subset B$ then $B^+ \subset A^+$.

Suppose $A,B$ are closed convex cones. Then we will show that $(A \cap B)^+ = A^++B^+$.

Since $A\cap B \subset A$ we have $A^+ \subset (A \cap B)^+$ and similarly for $B$. Since $ (A \cap B)^+$ is a convex cone, we have $A^++B^+ \subset (A \cap B)^+$.

To show the other direction, it is sufficient to show that
$(A^++B^+)^+ \subset (A \cap B)^{++} = A\cap B$.

Suppose $x \in (A^++B^+)^+$, then
$\langle x, \alpha + \beta \rangle \ge 0$ for all $\alpha \in A^+, \beta \in B^+$. Setting $\beta =0$ shows that $x \in A^{++} = A$ and similarly for $B$ which shows that $x \in A \cap B$, the desired result.

Finally, it is straightforward to show that $(\mathbb{R}^n_+)^+ = \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $({\cal R} A^T)^+ = ({\cal R} A^T)^\bot = \ker A$.